# Include environment in package built with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, travis-ci, conda

We have a python/conda package with lots of dependencies. In order to make installation easier, we've made a miniconda environment which works consistently with our package. We'd like to bundle this environment into the `requirements: run:` section of the `meta.yaml` both for other users to install from, and to run tests on TravisCI.

Ideally, when someone downloads and installs our package, all of these dependencies would also be downloaded and installed via conda. Same goes for when we run tests on TravisCI.

- Is there a way to do this?
- Does this affect the `conda_upload.sh` or `build.sh` scripts?
- Would we then be ok to just install the package on travis for testing then automatically upload to conda and pip when the tests pass?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question(s). If there are packages that are required for your package to work, you should include them in the `requirements/run` section and they will be installed at the install time of your package. However, if they are not required for your package to work, then they should not be listed. `conda-build` will automatically handle installing any dependencies in `requirements/run`.

Comment: So there's no need for an `environment.yaml` if the run requirements contain all of that information? Can I specify the channels that the requirements are installed from?

Comment: 1) Yes, but you should really only list packages that are required (e.g., imported in a Python package) in `requirements/run`. Everything else should go in an `environment.yaml`. 2) You can specify the channels in an `environment.yaml` but not in `requirements/run`. `conda-build` will use the channels specified in the conda configuration on the build machine, and users who install the package will resolve any dependencies from their own channels.

Comment: Some of the required packages come from specific conda channels, I'm not sure how I can include those packages in the `meta.yaml` requirements if I can't specify those channels anywhere (except the `environment.yaml`). Also, how can users use the `environment.yaml` if it isn't built into the package? Thanks

Comment: Your users (or you while building the package) will have to add those channels to their configuration. Since it is possible that many channels could resolve any given dependency, conda prefers that users choose which channels to use rather than package maintainers specifying. You have the `-c` or `--channel` switch (which can be specified multiple times) to the `conda install`, `conda create`, and `conda build` commands. Or, you can do `conda config --add channels <channel-name>` to use it for all commands.

Comment: If you would prefer your users to use `environment.yaml` just post it somewhere (on a website, etc.) and have users download it or copy it into their own file.